# Quantstats - TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns, America/New_York] and datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, anaconda3

I'm trying to use some of the Quantstats modules, specifically the quantstats.reports module, in Anaconda to get some metrics reports on a portfolio I've designed. I'm fairly new to Python/Quantstats and am really just trying to get a feel for the library.

I've written the following code to utilize the report module to spit out a complete html report and save it under the Output folder:

```
import quantstats as qs

qs.extend_pandas()

stock = qs.utils.download_returns('GLD')

qs.reports.html(stock, output='Output/GLD.html')
```

I then get the following TypeError:

```
TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns, America/New_York] and datetime
```

I believe this may be a result of the datetime64 class being localized to my timezone and datetime remaining TZ naive. Frankly, digging through the Quantstats code has been a little beyond my current skillset.

If anybody has any recommendations for fixes, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, in pandas 2.0 this fixed it:

```
df.index = df.index.tz_convert(None)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I came upon this while DDGing exactly the same issue.
Not sure which of your columns has the timezone localisation in it, but

```
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.tz_localize(None)
```

will get rid of localization for the column df['date']

Incidentally, the usual situation is that the index of a pandas timeseries contains np.Datetime64 types, but when you assign it to a column via

```
df['date'] = df.index
```

the resulting column contains pandas Timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue resolved after I had lowered the yfinance version from latest version 0.1.87 to

yfinance => 0.1.74

Answer (score 0):

For the Quantstats specifically, you need to convert the benchmark as well as the returns series:

```
returns.index = returns.index.tz_convert(None)
benchmark = pd.DataFrame(qs.utils.download_returns('SPY'))
benchmark.index = benchmark.index.tz_localize(None)
qs.reports.html(returns, benchmark=benchmark)
```

Reference:
https://github.com/ranaroussi/quantstats/issues/245